# Javascript menuext window.external.menuArguments.event.srcElement.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a video url from the site, https://yandex.com/video/ via IE's menuext function that runs javascript.

So from the left in the page, how can i get the url of right-clicked element (video) via something like window.external.menuArguments.event.srcElement.getElementsByClassName

I think it's simple but I could not.

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = window.external.menuArguments.event.srcElement.outerHTML;
if (link.indexOf('href":"') > -1){
link = link.substring(link.indexOf('href":"') +7);
link = link.substring(0, link.indexOf('"'));}
```